# django rest framework aggregation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to group ingredients by product, let me explain.

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    """
    modelo generico di un prodoto vendibile al cliente
    """
    name = models.CharField(
        "nome del prodotto",
        max_length=25,
        unique=True,
    )
    cost = models.DecimalField(
        "costo",
        max_digits= 5,
        decimal_places= 2,
    )
    classification = models.ForeignKey(
        Classification, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name="prodotti",
        verbose_name="classificazione"
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Prodotto"
        verbose_name_plural = "Prodotti"

class IngredientProductRelation(models.Model):
    """
    modelo intermedio utilizato per memorizare le relazione da ingredienti e 
    prodoti
    """
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="ingredients",
        verbose_name="prodotto"
    )
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="products",
        verbose_name="ingrediente"
    )
    quantity = models.FloatField("quantità")

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.product} - {self.ingredient}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "ingrediente"
        verbose_name_plural = "ingrediente"
```

**serializers.py**

```
class IngredientProductRelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    model = IngredientProductRelation
    fields = ['ingredient', 'quantity']

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    #ingredients = IngredientProductRelationSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'classification', 'ingredients']
```

**views.py**

```
class IngredientViewsets(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

**at this moment I get an error if I do not comment "ingredients = IngredientProductRelationSerializer (read_only = True, many = True)" and then I am forced to comment and visualize this**

```
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "spritz",
            "classification": 2,
            "ingredients": [
                1,
                2,
                3
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Prosecco",
            "classification": 6,
            "ingredients": []
        }
```

**error**

```
e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\pagination.py:200: UnorderedObjectListWarning: Pagination may yield inconsistent results with an unordered object_list: <class 'products.models.Product'> QuerySet.
  paginator = self.django_paginator_class(queryset, page_size)
Internal Server Error: /products/api/ingredient/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view      
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch     
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch     
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 43, in list
    return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 745, in data   
    ret = super().data
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 246, in data   
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 663, in to_representation
    return [
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 664, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 663, in to_representation
    return [
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 664, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 500, in to_representation
    for field in fields:
  File "e:\githab\bar-manager\py_bar\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 361, in _readable_fields
    for field in self.fields.values():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

**for I don't understand why you don't let me view this**

```
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "spritz",
            "classification": 2,
            "ingredients": [
                {
                "ingredient": 7,
                "quantity": 250.0,
                },
                {
                "ingredient": 9
                "quantity": 100.0,
                },
                {
                "ingredient": 8
                 "quantity": 100.0,
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Prosecco",
            "classification": 6,
            "ingredients": []
        }
```

I hope I've been exhaustive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would design the code like this:

**Models**

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
   # Put here ingredient info
   class Meta:
        verbose_name = "ingrediente"
        verbose_name_plural = "ingredienti"


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        "nome del prodotto",
        max_length=25,
        unique=True,
    )
    cost = models.DecimalField(
        "costo",
        max_digits= 5,
        decimal_places= 2,
    )
    classification = models.ForeignKey(
        Classification, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name="prodotti",
        verbose_name="classificazione"
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Prodotto"
        verbose_name_plural = "Prodotti"


class IngredientProductRelation(models.Model):
    """
    This is an intermediate model used to relate ingredients and products
    """
    # You can also use a ManyToManyField with a through model, but i think that in this case is not convenient
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="ingredients",
        verbose_name="prodotto"
    )
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(
        Ingredient,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="products",
        verbose_name="ingrediente"
    )
    quantity = models.FloatField("quantità")
```

**Serializers**:

```
class IngredientProductRelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializes a IngredientProductRelation instance
    """
    class Meta:
        model = IngredientProductRelation
        fields = ['ingredient', 'quantity']


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializes a Product instance
    """
    ingredients = IngredientProductRelationSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'classification', 'ingredients']
```

**Views**:

```
class ProductViewsets(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

A serialized Product instance should look like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "example",
  "classification": "example",
  "ingredients":[
      {
       "ingredient": 7,
       "quantity": 250.0,
      },
      {
       "ingredient": 1,
       "quantity": 100.0,
      },
   ]
}
```

You can also access products associated with a given ingredient, for example:

```
ingredient_product_relations = ingredient.products.all()
for ingredient_product_relation in list(ingredient_product_relations):
    print(ingredient_product_relation.product.name)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I just wanted to tell you that as soon as I add an object in "IngredientProductRelation" I am wrong, dicendomi : "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'"

Comment: I experimented a bit and managed to print only the id of the relation, removing "ingredients = IngredientProductRelationSerializer (read_only = True, many = True)".
but I can't see the information that interests me overo "'ingredient', 'quantity'"

Comment: I have corrected an error in the IngredientProductRelation.ingredient field (wrong related model). Now if you want to create a IngredientProductRelation instance can write: `IngredientProductRelation.objects.create(product=1, ingredient=1, quantity=100)` or:  `IngredientProductRelation.objects.bulk_create([IngredientProductRelation(product=1, ingredient=1, quantity=100), IngredientProductRelation(product=2, ingredient=1, quantity=200)])`

Comment: @FabioZorzetto i have updated my answer, now it should work, now don t translate related name of IngredientProductRelation foreign keys or the code will not work

Comment: @RossoCarriola I changed the problem that now happens with the changes made thanks to your help

Comment: i just solved practically in "Ingredient Product Relation Serializer" the "Meta" class is missing, thanks for your help @RossoCarriola

Comment: @FabioZorzetto ok I have edited my answer, excuse me for errors. Remember to update the related model of the field in IngredientProductRelation model: `ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="products", verbose_name="ingrediente")`